# Using a newer version of Python than what is installed on Linux server

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, admin

I have an account on a Linux server which currently has Python2.4 installed on it so by default running the command `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`

I have installed Python2.7 in my account home directory @ /path/to/myaccount and have set and sourced the path in my .bash_profile file as

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/myaccount/bin/python
export PATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PATH
```

However I am still getting Python2.4 as my default Python.

Comment: Although this isn’t a direct solution for enabling the version of Python you’ve installed, you might want to take a look at [Virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), which allows each of your Python projects to have its own isolated Python install (and installed modules).

Comment: how did you set the path?

Comment: `.bash_profile` is only sourced in login shells, I believe. I'm guessing that either logging out and back in, or putting this in `.bashrc` instead would do the trick.

Comment: Edited to include how path is set.

Comment: Try to use "which python2.7" and put this path as shebang #!/path/to/myaccount/bin/python2.7

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? use 2.7 for specific tasks or you want to replace the *system* default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PYTHONPATH` tells Python where to look for modules and packages (`.py` files etc)

You need to make sure your *shell* is looking in the right place for the Python binary

```
export PATH=/path/to/myaccount/bin:$PATH
```